# Error - argument "inputId" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Trying to get a numeric input and apply 2 formulas on the input and use them to plot histograms.

UI Side

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  actionButton (InputId = "USD", label = "US Bond Return"),
  actionButton (InputId = "INR", label = "Indian Bond Return"),
  numericInput(InputId = "num", label = "USD given by Investor", value = 0, 
min = 1, max = 1000, step = NA, width = NULL), plotOutput("hist")))
```

Server Side

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

rv = reactiveValues(data = input$num)
observeEvent(input$USD, { rv$data <- (input$num * 0.0225) })
observeEvent(input$INR, { rv$data <- (input$num*0.1) })

output$curve <- renderPlot({
hist(rv$data)
})
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your ui. Its not `InputId`, its `inputId`(notice the small i).

Therefore your ui code will be as follows:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    actionButton (inputId = "USD", label = "US Bond Return"),
    actionButton (inputId = "INR", label = "Indian Bond Return"),
    numericInput(inputId = "num", label = "USD given by Investor", value = 0, 
                 min = 1, max = 1000, step = NA, width = NULL), plotOutput("hist")))
```

Comment: Thanks ! That error has now been resolved but now it is throwing other error :-  Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: That error is because of `rv = reactiveValues(data = input$num)` . Why don't you try  `rv = reactiveValues(data = input$num)`.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve cannot be achieved from your code because the `observeEvent` is called when you click the button which you do after the initial run of the app. Your `renderPlot({
hist(rv$data)})` runs during the initial run of the app and never gets called again. Consider referring [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/plotOutput.html) to understand how shiny app works. Also, [Shiny App Tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) is a great place from where you can learn.